# SQL Trigger information

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, relational-database

I have a general question about Triggers. Is there anyway to program the SQL database in a way that whenever a trigger is fired, SQL tells us what rows of data were removed or edited to meet one's criteria. In my case, I am using postgreSQL and I have one specific trigger which deletes certain rows being inserted in a table if a certain criteria is met. Is there anything I can add or change settings in postgreSQL that will indicate to me what rows and how many rows were deleted in this case:

```
CREATE TRIGGER unknowns
AFTER INSERT
ON  employees
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_rows();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_rows()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM employees WHERE Customer = 'unknown';
 RETURN NEW;
END;   
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: @No Name, it triggers fine in my database. Please feel to modify if you can make it better, I just want to get notified on how many rows get deleted once the table is inserted.

Comment: It seems you are looking for an audit trigger. See [here](http://cjauvin.blogspot.de/2013/05/impossibly-lean-audit-system-for.html) or [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)

Answer (score 1):

You would not typically do this at the database level.

Normally, you would modify the trigger to store changed data in an archive/history table.  Then you will have a record of the data that has changed, when it was changed, and who changed it.

If you specifically want to know about changes *initiated* in a trigger, I'm not sure if there is any mechanism to distinguish those changes from user-initiated changes.

Comment: In an archive/history table....How is this possible? I want to keep record of data changed/deleted.

Comment: @AQDeveloper . . . One method is to have triggers that record any changes to the table by inserting into the history/archive table.

Comment: How can I make this table @ Gordon? First time I heard about such a tactic.